# TypeError: autodiscover_tasks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'packages'. Celery

Tags: django, celery

I am taking the first steps to add Celery tasks in the background in my Django application. But I still receive the error.

```
  File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\send_sms_oferia\app_rama\app_rama\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .celery import app as celery_app
  File "C:\Users\tymot\Desktop\send_sms_oferia\app_rama\app_rama\celery.py", line 17, in <module>
    app.autodiscover_tasks()
TypeError: autodiscover_tasks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'packages'
```

Where can this error come from? How can I solve it?

I try to perform my steps in accordance with this [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps), so my file looks like this:
celery.py (in my project directory):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app_rama.settings')

app = Celery('app_rama')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

My `__init__.py` file (in my project directory)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try passing passing installed apps to `autodiscover_tasks` like so:

```
from django.conf import settings
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

[Check the documentation on this function](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.autodiscover_tasks)